# Irreducible Polynomials $GF(2^4)$: Why is $x^4 + x^2 + 1$ reducible?

Tags: finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I am currently working with $GF(2)$, in particular with $GF(2^4)$. One task is to find all irreducible polynomials. I have found ways of reducing the list of all candidates drastically. In my current list of irreducibles there is still ***one*** polynomial left which shouldn't be there:

$x^4+x^2+1$

I don't know why this one is ***reducible***. How can I factorize this polynomial?

Comment: Hint: there aren't that many (three to be precise) irreducible polynomials of degree${}\leq2$ over $GF(2)$. And only $16$ polynomials of degree$~4$ in all. Eratosthenes' sieve is quite doable, by hand.

Comment: I don't know about Eratosthene's sieve, but I'll check it out now. Might come handy later. Thank you @MarcvanLeeuwen.

Comment: Eratosthene's sieve is just the age-old method of throwing out all multiples of known smaller primes so that what's left over are then also (larger) primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$(x^2+x+1)^2 = x^4+x^2+1$ by Freshmen's Dream.

On the other hand, let $f$ be a polynomial of degree $4$ over $\mathbb F_2$, which has no roots. Then $f$ is either irreducible or decomposes into two irreducible factors of degree $2$. But $x^2+x+1$ is the only irreducible of degree $2$, hence we get $f=(x^2+x+1)^2$. So your polynomial is the only reducible polynomial of degree $4$ without roots.

Comment: I have not stated anything about the number of irreduible quartics.

Comment: Reducible, not IRreducible!

Comment: Thank you MooS. That explains why my other criterias didnt eliminate this polynom. When you say "without roots" does it equal to not having zeros (e.g. $f(1)!=0$)?

Comment: Yes, that was supposed to mean $f(1)=1=f(0)$, which means precisley that there is an odd number of monomials occuring and the constant term is $1$. In particular $x^4+x^3+1$ and $x^4+x+1$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ are indeed irreducible.

Comment: Thank you very much again MooS, for the quick and clear response! :)

Comment: @Moos Thanks for explanations.

Answer (score 1):

for any prime $p$ and $\{a_j \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ you have:

$$
\sum_{j=0}^n a_j x^{b_j p} \equiv_p \left(\sum _{j=0}^n a_j x^{b_j}\right)^p
$$

using $p=2$ the given polynomial $x^4+x^2+1 \equiv_2 (x^2+x^1+1)^2$

btw, if you are looking at irreducible polynomials in finite fields it is useful to know how many irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ there are over the field with $q$ elements.

this is 
$$
\rho(n) = \frac1{n} \sum_{d|n} \mu(\frac{n}{d}) q^d
$$
in the case $q=2, n=4$ this evaluates to $\frac14(2^4-2^2)=3$. these are $x^4+x^3+1, x^4+x+1$ and $x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$.